# Installing Cassandra in a Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hdfs, nosql

In a Hadoop Cluster, we want to install Cassandra. 
Is the way to Install Cassandra so that, i will be able to insert the data directly into the hdfs.

For e.g. With Hbase, we have to mention the hbase.rootdir under hbase-site.xml.

```
<property>
 <name> hbase.rootdir </name>
 <Value> hdfs://<hostname>:<portnumber>/hbase  </Value>
</property>
```

So, with one Master and n-regionservers, we were able to use Hbase as a Multi-node set up.

Note : instructions available on http://hbase.apache.org/

Similarly, Is it possible to Install Cassandra as a Muti-node setup.(similar to hbase set up)

Is it possible to mention hdfs url in  data_file_directories parameter under cassandra.yaml

```
data_file_directories:
    - hdfs://<hostname>:<portnumber>/Cassandra
```

I was not able to find any articles which guides with this kind of a setup.
Any guidance/suggestions in setting up Cassandra, on the Hadoop cluster would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: did you found solution

Answer (score 0):

Try [Datastax Brisk](http://blog.octo.com/en/introduction-to-datastax-brisk-an-hadoop-and-cassandra-distribution/) - an Hadoop and Cassandra distribution